# Why is antheridiophore not considered part of the sex organ while stamens including filament are considered a sex organ?

Tags: reproduction, plant-anatomy

In the majority of websites and textbook I have referenced, the antheridiophore is considered to be the stalk which extends the sex organ (antheridium) in bryophytes. Meanwhile, in flowers, the whole stamen, that is, the filament also is considered a part of the sex organ. Is there any reason behind this?